# How to configure WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0 to work with Identity Server 5.4.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I cannot find any step by step article in the poor WSO2 documentation for how to configure IS **5.4.1** as a Key Manager to AM **2.1.0** (*these to versions in particular*). Can someone provide me an up to date article or a tutorial how to do the configuration for these versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0 is only compatible with WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 [1]. Due to the complexities, you cannot run APIM 2.1.0 with IS 5.4.1.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+the+Key+Manager+in+WSO2+API+Manager

Comment: Should I consider the prepackaged or stand alone IS? What is included in prepackaged exactly - is it only IS or (IS + AM)? Why do I have to configure the API Manager as well? The documentation is not very clear to me

Comment: Prepackaged WSO2 IS has Identity features as well as APIM key manager features. If you are looking for IS to work as key manager, you have to use IS prepackaged pack. All the key validation, key issuing calls will be sent to IS node when running in IS as KM mode. That's why you need to configure API Manager.

Comment: So I download wso2is-km-5.3.0 only (which includes all the needed configurations already done?) and then I download the wso2am-2.1.0 that I need to configure manually by myself, following the documentation step by step, right? Is this the only requirement for an Integrated IS + AM - only IS to act as a Key Manager?

Comment: yes, This will help - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager

Comment: That's good but after the configurations, how to test it if it's configured right? When I create a user in IS should it appear in AM?

Comment: Yes, it should appear.. I hope you tested the API invoke test. i.e creating an API, subscribe and invoke.

Comment: I haven't configured everything yet. I have problems with Step 3. I want to use the built in H2 database, so do I have to go through this Step 3?

Comment: H2 is not recommended in the production environment. You need to use any mysql, oracle or any supported db. You need to go through step 3 and share relevant databases within the products.